# How to specify multiple options using apache commons cli?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I want something like:

```
java programName  -jobs1 -C 10 -W 20
java programName  -job2
java programName  -job3
```

With contents:

```
Option o1 = new Option("job2", "some desc");
Option o2 = new Option("job3" , "(some desc")

Option o3 = OptionBuilder.hasArgs(2).withArgName( "W" ).withArgName("C").withDescription(  "Some desc" ).create("job1")
Option o4 = new Option("help");

Options os = new Options().addOption(o1).addOption(o2).addOption(o3).addOption(o4).

HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
formatter.printHelp( "ProgramName", options );
```

...where the output is:

```
Usage ProgramName
 -job1 <c>  Some Desc
 -job2      Some desc
 -job3      Some desc
 -help      Print this message
```

I expect for `-job1` it should print `-job1 -C <>   -W <>`

Am I missing something? It doesn't work with more than one argument. By the way, I used `commons-cli 1.2`.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding `hasArgs()` and `withArgName()`.

Comment: It seems that this cannot be done using apache-commons-cli - An apache library that does very little. I expected more. I'll try and see how if I can add some more functionality...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have context-sensitive arguments.  You can have the arguments: job1, job2, job3, C & W, but you cannot say (through the library) that C & W are only valid for job1.

If job1/2/3 are mutually exclusive, create an OptionGroup.  Then in code, make sure C & W are only given for job1.

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionGroup;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;

public class StackOverflowExample
{
    public static final String JOB1 = "job1";
    public static final Option job1 =
        OptionBuilder.hasArg(false)
            .isRequired(false)
            .withDescription("description of job1")
            .create(JOB1);

    public static final String JOB2 = "job2";
    public static final Option job2 =
        OptionBuilder.hasArg(false)
            .isRequired(false)
            .withDescription("description of job2")
            .create(JOB2);

    public static final String JOB3 = "job3";
    public static final Option job3 =
        OptionBuilder.hasArg(false)
            .isRequired(false)
            .withDescription("description of job3")
            .create(JOB3);

    public static final String MY_C = "C";
    public static final Option my_c =
        OptionBuilder.hasArg(true)
            .withArgName("count")
            .isRequired(false)
            .withDescription("description of C")
            .create(MY_C);

    public static final String MY_W = "W";
    public static final Option my_w =
        OptionBuilder.hasArg(true)
            .withArgName("width")
            .isRequired(false)
            .withDescription("description of W")
            .create(MY_W);


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Options options = new Options();

        OptionGroup optgrp = new OptionGroup();
        optgrp.addOption(job1);
        optgrp.addOption(job2);
        optgrp.addOption(job3);

        options.addOptionGroup(optgrp);
        options.addOption(my_c);
        options.addOption(my_w);

        try {
            CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
            CommandLine cmdline = parser.parse(options, args);

            if (((cmdline.hasOption(MY_C)) || (cmdline.hasOption(MY_W))) &&
                (! cmdline.hasOption(JOB1))) {
                HelpFormatter help = new HelpFormatter();
                help.printHelp("cmdname", options);
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
<~/sandbox/CoreUtils/scratch> $ javac -d . -cp ~/sandbox/CoreUtils/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:. StackOverflowExample.java
<~/sandbox/CoreUtils/scratch> $ java -cp ~/sandbox/CoreUtils/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:. StackOverflowExample -C foo -job1
OK

<~/sandbox/CoreUtils/scratch> $ java -cp ~/sandbox/CoreUtils/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:. StackOverflowExample -C foo -job2
usage: cmdname
 -C <count>   description of C
 -job1        description of job1
 -job2        description of job2
 -job3        description of job3
 -W <width>   description of W
```

Comment: The way you have created `job1` is not even compiling, I am uing maven with version 1.2 for dependency, how did you make it work?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466955/java-apache-cli-optionbuilder-not-working-as-builder-pattern?lq=1

Comment: you're sample doesn't work. is it possible to define at the same time an OptionGroup and an option for the Options ?

Comment: I've added the imports, the class structure and the try/catch block.

Comment: @Kakawait - I don't understand your question.