# Java Apache CLI OptionBuilder not working as Builder pattern

Tags: java, apache, command-line-interface

I want to do something like

```java
public static final Option job1 =
    OptionBuilder.hasArg(false)
        .isRequired(false)
        .withDescription("description of job1")
        .create(JOB1);
```

as mentioned [How to specify multiple options using apache commons cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304431/how-to-specify-multiple-options-using-apache-commons-cli)

I am using maven dependency as

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

as mentioned here - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.1

But I am not able to, compiler complains

`static member org.apache.commons.cli.OptionsBuilder.create() accessed via instance reference`

, I even tried with `<version>1.2</version>`, but no luck, am I missing something?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that every method in `OptionBuilder` is static, operating on static fields and returning a single static instance. Hence you don't require an instance of `OptionBuilder` to execute the methods. This doesn't marry well with the natural desire to chain the calls together, as you've done.

There is no solution other than to either calm the compiler down (perhaps disabling warnings in your IDE?) or adjust your code as follows (untested):

```
public static final Option job1;

static {
    OptionBuilder.hasArg(false);
    OptionBuilder.isRequired(false)
    OptionBuilder.withDescription("description of job1")
    job1 = OptionBuilder.create(JOB1);
}
```

It would be better if the `OptionBuilder` class was rewritten with a public no-argument constructor and only instance methods, thus behaving like every other builder out there. There is an existing bug in the commons-cli issue tracker highlighting this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLI-224

*Update: my patch has been submitted to trunk, so a new "proper" builder will be available in the next release of commons-cli (v1.3). See Javadocs [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html)*.

Comment: The supression you need is `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")`, then you can use eg.: `Option optionHelp = OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("help").withDescription("print program usage").create("h");`even though it is a design flaw, that every method is static - as @Duncan Jones mentioned.